# The difference between "goes to infinity" and "goes off to infinity"?

Tags: infinity

I am currently reading the book ''[The Outer Limits of Reason](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17841838-the-outer-limits-of-reason)'' and encountered a description about which I am very confused. I am afraid to say, this may be due to the fact that I am not a native English speaker.

on pp.61, it says:

> Again there is a mathematical analogy to this. In calculus we say that the limit of
>   1/x as x **goes to infinity** is zero. That is, the larger x gets, the closer 1/x gets to zero.
>   Since infinity is not a number, x can never get to infinity and 1/x can never get to zero.
>   But the concept of a limit makes it meaningful. Similarly, the distance between
>   Achilles and the Tortoise will never really be zero but the limit of the distance does
>   get to zero. Again, we can find fault with this analogy. The concept of a mathematical
>   limit is a type of trick. For no finite number will 1/x actually equal zero and at no
>   time period will Achilles actually reach the Tortoise

and on pp.191, it says:

> The Mandelbrot set is an easily describable set of
>   complex numbers. Start with a complex number c, square it, and add c to the result.
>   This gives you another complex number. Square this number and add c to it again.
>   Iteratively continue this procedure over and over again—that is, take the complex
>   number z, calculate z2 + c, and repeat.5 Either of two things can happen to the
>   numbers in this iteration:
>
> • They can get bigger and bigger until they **go off to infinity**.
>
> • The complex numbers can remain small.

I think I know that when we say "as x goes to infinity" it means that "as x is moving towards infinity", right? But I wanted to know is "goes off to infinity" means the same thing or means that "it reaches to infinity"? or it means something different?

Comment: consider $\lim\limits_{x\to\color{blue}\infty}\dfrac1x=0$ vs. $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac 1x=\color{blue}\infty$

Comment: They mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard calculus, nothing ever reaches infinity. However, they can grow without bound. There are many phrases we use to describe this phenomenon, because it's a very common thing and our books would get very monotonous if we used the same phrase every single time.

Yes, they all mean the same.